# Use current property value in ternary operator

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to decorate input based on some boolean flag.
If flag is On - I need change edge insets.
If flag is Off - I need no changes and want to use current value of contentPadding (instead of ????)

```
TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: someBoolFlagIsOn ? EdgeInsets.zero.copyWith(left: 10) : ????,
```

How can I do that in ternary operator?

Comment: Just passing `null` should work.

Answer (score 1):

@Artem Zyuzko Please take a moment to review the code below. I think it could be really helpful.

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: someBoolFlagIsOn
        ? EdgeInsets.zero.copyWith(left: 10)
        : InputDecoration().contentPadding,
  ),
)
```

If `someBoolFlagIsOn` is true, it applies `EdgeInsets.zero.copyWith(left: 10)` as the content padding. If false, it uses the current contentPadding value by creating a new InputDecoration and accessing its contentPadding property.

**Output:**

When `someBoolFlagIsOn` is true, or in other words, under the condition that `someBoolFlagIsOn` is true.

[image]

When `someBoolFlagIsOn` is not true, or in other words, when it is false.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could just assign a different decoration without the contentPadding in that case. So like

```
      TextField(
          decoration: someBoolFlagIsOn
              ? InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero.copyWith(left: 10))
              : const InputDecoration()),
```